# Python 3.9.1 pip install python-binance win32 visualstudio

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip

Should
pip install python-binance
function under
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
?

I have installed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.8.4

but get the errors:

```
c:\users\---\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'<br>
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8421): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3<br>
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8437): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3<br>
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2<br>
```

Thank you for any suggestions. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, this happens after installing Visual Studio Build Tools and  Visual C++ build tools